# Цикл while в Python

Tags: python, алгоритм, циклы

почему когда я ввожу цикл while в Python 3 со знаком ==

```
while x == 10:
```

То цикл не работает, но при введении

```
while x <= 10:
```

Все работает?
Подскажите пожалуйста, только начал на Python программировать.

Comment: Вероятно, `x < 10`.

Comment: в первом варианте цикл будет работать пока значения `x` равно 10, очевидно у вас оно изначально не равно 10

Answer (score 5):

ну вы бы цикл показали бы, чтобы точно понимать что происходит

**`while`** - **`пока`**

т.е. выполняй тело цикла пока выполняется условие цикла

```
x = 1

while x == 10:
    print(x)
    x += 1
```

понятно, что цикла не будет, ведь `x` не равно 10

```
x = 1

while x < 10:
    print(x)
    x += 1
```

в данном случае цикл будет выполнен 9 раз и будет выведено `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

Answer (score -1):

если  x  равен 10 то всё работает, но если x не равен 10 то нужно использовать "<" или ">" или "<=" или ">="